# GNU Parallel doesn't display colors when installed from source

Tags: configure, gnu-parallel

Does anyone know how to install GNU Parallel from source so that the output of certain commands are displayed with colors? I found that the  version 20170622 doesn't display colors when running, for example, [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) with DEBUG=nightmare.

```
DEBUG=nightmare parallel node my-script.js
```

and outputs:

[image]

However, the version installed via apt install in Ubuntu (20141022+ds1-1) maintains the colors:

[image]

Comment: **GNU Parallel** is not compiled, it is actually a **Perl** script. I guess it forks a shell to execute each job, so you would probably need to `export DEBUG=nightmare` to make sure that it is passed to forked jobs... though I have been wrong many times before! I don't know **nightmare** and don't feel like trying it - it doesn't sound good to me!

Comment: Yes, I know it is a perl script. I was referring to the configure, make, make install process. I will amend the question to correct that part. Are you sure about `export DEBUG=nightmare`? That part is passed to the command and its output is correctly displayed but without color.

Comment: I will defer to the author @OleTange

Comment: Make a MCVE (i.e include my-script.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume your program is:

```
echo myfoobar | grep --color foo
```

This gives colors if `grep` detects the output is a tty.

You can ask GNU Parallel to open the tty by using `--tty`. `--tty` defaults to `-j1` so you need to set that, too:

```
parallel -j100% --tty  'echo myfoobar | grep --color' ::: foo
```

The problem is, that buffering is also disabled, so it activates `--ungroup`, and that is why this is not default. As you can see here the outputs of the jobs mix:

```
fu() { echo myfoobar | grep --color "$@"; }
env_parallel -j100% --tty  'echo {}; fu {};sleep 0.1; echo {}; fu {}' ::: foo fo f b ba bar
```

Comment: Excellent. That's the flag I was looking or. Any idea why the installer for Ubuntu already gives you the `--tty` behavior?

Comment: Nope. I walked through the package and cannot see any signs of this.

Comment: Very unusual. Anyway, thank you for the great tool. By the way, do you have a link to send some "beer money"? I only see https://gnuparallel.threadless.com/designs/gnu-parallel.

Comment: If you like GNU parallel: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Spread-the-word

Comment: Yes. I suppose https://my.fsf.org/donate is the more appropriate way to contribute. It would be nice to have an option for small personal donations, though.